# How to use Generics to simplify my Edit Method

Tags: java, generics, java.util.scanner

In my program, I am trying to create a method that will Edit any property inside of a BaseContact. BaseContact is an abstract class that is extended within a PersonContact and BusinessContact classes. I want to create an edit method that asks the user what property they want to edit, shows them the old value, and then updates with the new value they want. I reuse a lot of code so I was thinking of trying to make another method that will help recycle code, but I'm unsure how that would work with the need of unique getters and setters.

```
public void editQuery() {
    
}

// Edit BaseContact
public void edit(int id) {
    try {
        contacts.contains(contacts.get(id - 1));
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("Contact does not exist\n--- EXIT ---");
        return;
    }
    Boolean active = true;

    // While Statement for Edit
    while (active) {
        System.out.println(
                "What property would you like to edit?\n1. Name\n2. Phone Number\n3. Date of Birth\n4. Hobby\n5. Description"
                        + "\n6. Website URL\n7. Hours of Operation\n8. Street\n9. City\n10. State\n11. Zip Code\n12. Location"
                        + "\n13. Relatives" + "\n14. Photos\n15. Exit");

        String choice = sc.nextLine();
        switch (choice.toUpperCase()) {

        case "1":
        case "NAME":
            for (BaseContact contact : contacts) {
                if (contact.getId() == id) {
                    System.out.println("Contact Name: " + contact.getName() + "\n");
                    System.out.print("New Name: ");
                    String name = sc.nextLine();
                    contact.setName(name);
                    System.out.println("Contact Name Set To: " + contact.getName());
                }
            }
            break;
        case "3":
        case "DATE OF BIRTH":
            for (BaseContact contact : contacts) {
                if (contact.getId() == id) {
                    if (contact.getType().equals("personContact")) {
                        PersonContact temp = (PersonContact) contact;
                        System.out.println("Contact Date of Birth (ex. January 01, 1999): " + temp.getDob() + "\n");
                        System.out.print("New Date of Birth: ");
                        String dob = sc.nextLine();
                        temp.setDob(dob);
                        System.out.println("Contact Date of Birth Set To: " + temp.getDob());
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case "10":
        case "STATE":
            for (BaseContact contact : contacts) {
                if (contact.getId() == id) {
                    System.out.println("Contact State: " + contact.getLocation().getState());
                    System.out.print("New State: ");
                    String state = sc.nextLine();
                    contact.getLocation().setState(state);
                    System.out.println("Contact State Set To: " + contact.getLocation().getState());
                }
            }
            break;
        case "12":
        case "LOCATION":
            for (BaseContact contact : contacts) {
                if (contact.getId() == id) {
                    // Location
                    Location location = createLocation();
                    contact.getLocation().setStreet(location.getStreet());
                    contact.getLocation().setCity(location.getCity());
                    contact.getLocation().setState(location.getState());
                    contact.getLocation().setZipCode(location.getZipCode());
                    System.out.println("Contact Location Set To: " + contact.getLocation());
                }
            }
            break;

        case "13":
        case "RELATIVES":
            for (BaseContact contact : contacts) {
                if (contact.getId() == id) {
                    if (contact.getType().equals("personContact")) {
                        PersonContact temp = (PersonContact) contact;
                        System.out.println("List of Relatives");
                        System.out.print("Contact Relatives: ");
                        for (int i = 0; i < temp.getRelatives().size(); i++) {
                            System.out.println(temp.getRelatives().get(i).getName());
                        }
                        System.out.println("Would you like to 1. Add or 2. Remove relatives?");
                        String rChoice = sc.nextLine();
                        // Adding Relative
                        if (rChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("1") || rChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("ADD")) {
                            System.out.println("--- Add Relatives ---");
                            System.out.println("List of Available Contacts\n");
                            for (BaseContact rcontact : contacts) {
                                if (rcontact.getType().equals("personContact")) {
                                    PersonContact rtemp = (PersonContact) rcontact;
                                    System.out.print(rtemp.getName() + " | ");
                                }
                            }
                            System.out.println();
                            System.out.println("How many relatives would you like to add?");
                            int numOfRelatives = sc.nextInt();
                            sc.nextLine();
                            for (int i = 0; i < numOfRelatives; i++) {
                                System.out.println("--- Add Relative ---");
                                System.out.print("Relative Name: ");
                                String rname = sc.nextLine();
                                for (BaseContact r2contact : contacts) {
                                    if (r2contact.getType().equals("personContact")) {
                                        PersonContact r2temp = (PersonContact) r2contact;
                                        if (rname.equalsIgnoreCase(r2temp.getName())) {
                                            temp.getRelatives().add(r2temp);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            // Removing Relative
                        } else if (rChoice.equals("2") || rChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("REMOVE")) {
                            System.out.println("--- Remove Relatives ---");
                            System.out.println("List of Relatives");
                            for (int i = 0; i < temp.getRelatives().size(); i++) {
                                System.out.println(temp.getRelatives().get(i).getName());
                            }
                            System.out.println();
                            System.out.println("How many relatives would you like to remove?");
                            int numOfRelatives = sc.nextInt();
                            sc.nextLine();
                            if (numOfRelatives > temp.getRelatives().size()
                                    || numOfRelatives == temp.getRelatives().size()) {
                                temp.getRelatives().clear();
                                System.out.println("All Relatives Removed");
                            } else {
                                for (int i = 0; i < numOfRelatives; i++) {
                                    System.out.println("--- Remove Relative ---");
                                    System.out.print("Relative Name: ");
                                    String rName = sc.nextLine();
                                    for (BaseContact r2contact : contacts) {
                                        if (r2contact.getType().equals("personContact")) {
                                            PersonContact r2temp = (PersonContact) r2contact;
                                            if (rName.equalsIgnoreCase(r2temp.getName())) {
                                                temp.getRelatives().remove(r2temp);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Invalid Option");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
```

Comment: Readability is poor here. Please, narrow down your question to the specific piece you're having a doubt in. It's really inconvenient to read such a huge snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ask and thou shall receive. I have looked mainly at the humongous switch statement you have going on. For a starter, that should be condensed. A more functional style of programming can help here.

I had to deduce a lot of the classes you have used based on the methods which were called in the code. Furthermore, I have picked a couple of switch expressions and converted them in something more dynamic. See this as a starting point to build on for the rest of your application.

Start of with creating an action class for the simple edits:

```
public class ActionHolder {
 private final String actionText;
 private final BiConsumer<String, PersonContact> action;
 private final Function<PersonContact, String> originalValFunc;

 public ActionHolder(String actionText, BiConsumer<String, PersonContact> action,
                    Function<PersonContact, String> originalValFunc) {
     this.actionText = actionText;
     this.action = action;
     this.originalValFunc = originalValFunc;
 }

 public String getActionText() {
     return actionText;
 }

 public BiConsumer<String, PersonContact> getAction() {
     return action;
 }

 public Function<PersonContact, String> getOriginalValFunc() {
     return originalValFunc;
 }
}
```

The action class relies heavily on functional interfaces, make sure you read up on them thoroughly as they provide a powerful way of programming. (https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-functional-interfaces)

- actionText: Is used to label the attribute which is edited.
- action: A function which accepts two arguments and returns nothing.
  In this case we will use this to set the respective value on the
  PersonContact
- originalValFunc: A function to retrieve the origional value from the
  PersonContact, it is a function with one parameter (PersonContact)
  and it returns a string.

The edit method can then be build up as follows:

```
class TestInputProgram {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestInputProgram inputProgram = new TestInputProgram();
    inputProgram.edit(1);
}

private final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

//Initialize with temp data
private final ArrayList<PersonContact> contacts = new ArrayList<PersonContact>() {{
    add(new PersonContact(1));
}};

private static final Map<String, ActionHolder> actionMap = new HashMap<String, ActionHolder>() {{
    put("1", new ActionHolder("Contact Name",
            (input, contact) -> contact.setName(input), BaseContact::getName));
    put("NAME", new ActionHolder("Contact Name",
            (input, contact) -> contact.setName(input), BaseContact::getName));
    put("3", new ActionHolder("Date of Birth",
            (input, contact) -> contact.setDob(input), PersonContact::getDob));
    put("DATE OF BIRTH", new ActionHolder("Date of Birth",
            (input, contact) -> contact.setDob(input), PersonContact::getDob));
    put("10", new ActionHolder("State",
            (input, contact) -> contact.getLocation().setState(input),
            (contact -> contact.getLocation().getState())));
    put("STATE", new ActionHolder("State",
            (input, contact) -> contact.getLocation().setState(input),
            (contact -> contact.getLocation().getState())));
}};

// Edit BaseContact
public void edit(int id) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println(
                "What property would you like to edit?\n" +
                        "1. Name\n" +
                        "2. Phone Number\n" +
                        "3. Date of Birth\n" +
                        "15. Exit");

        String choice = sc.nextLine();
        if (Objects.equals(choice, "15")) {
            break;
        }

        PersonContact pContact = contacts.stream()
                .filter(contact -> contact.id == id)
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(
                        () -> new IllegalArgumentException("Contact with id: " + id + " does not exist!")
                );

        Optional.ofNullable(actionMap.get(choice.toUpperCase())).ifPresent(actionHolder -> {
            System.out.println(actionHolder.getActionText() + " current value: "
                    + actionHolder.getOriginalValFunc().apply(pContact) + "\n");
            System.out.println("Please provide the new value:");
            String newValue = sc.nextLine();
            actionHolder.getAction().accept(newValue, pContact);
            System.out.println(actionHolder.getActionText() + " set to: "
                    + actionHolder.getOriginalValFunc().apply(pContact));
            System.out.println("############################# \n");
        });
    }
}
}
```

Some brief info about the variables and whats going on:
The actionMap holds all the possible edit options we currently provide. Notice the implementation of the action holder arguments. We implement the actions using both lamda's and static method references. Inside the edit method the map is queried and the actionHolder retrieved. The respective input action info is then printed to the user and asked for input. The input is processed using the (BiConsumer) from the actionHolder.

I hope this will provide some reference for future programming optimization.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation. I will look into some of this further. You definitely are using advanced things I haven't learned about but I'm looking forward to learning it! :)